# Scrollbars for css menus still hidden behind PDFs in IE when using bgiframe

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pdf, scrollbar, bgiframe

So Bgiframe is a huge lifesaver - we have used it to tackle the IE PDF issue where is would hide our css dropdown menus. However, we have run into an issue - our css menus have a max height, and once that height is filled, they begin to use a scrollbar within the menu (think the Facebook notifications). bgiframe does an excellent job making sure that the menus themselves appear in front of the PDFs in IE, but the scrollbars in the menus do not - they and they alone are still hidden. We have inspected the elements to make sure that the menus and the bgiframe are the same, correct width, and they are - but the scrollbar is still hidden. This might be a bgiframe issue or an IE rendering issue, not sure. Nowhere - and I mean nowhere - have we been able to find anyone else with this kind of problem.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jscrollpane instead of the browser default scrollbar.  Also, make sure bgiframe covers the scrollbar area explicitly.